# How can I get an img button that plays audio when you click the button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the audio working but there is a problem with my img as button. They don't move together but separately. And its not just the img that is shown but also the button itself and I just want the img to be the button.

I also want the button to move to the back of the page and don't take up any space. 
When I use z-index: -1; the function of button disappears and it no longer works as a button.

Here is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<div class="omheen">
<div>
<audio id="audioContainer">
 <source src="spraakbericht.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<div id="memo">
 <button  id="play" onclick="playMp3()" type="button">
 <img class="memo" src="messages-05.png"/>
</div>
</button>
 <button id="pause" onclick="pauseMp3()" type="button">Pause Mp3</button> 

 </div>
</div>

<script>
 const audioContainer = document.getElementById("audioContainer"); 

 function playMp3() { 
  audioContainer.play(); 
} 

function pauseMp3() { 
 audioContainer.pause(); 
} 


</script>

<script>
 var play = document.getElementById("play");
 var pause = document.getElementById("play");
 play.innerHTML = '<img src="\messages-05.png" />';
 pause.innerHTML = '<img src="\messages-05.png" />';
</script>   





</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
     <input type="button" value="press play"  onclick="melody()">
       <audio id="html" src="anypath" ></audio>

      <script>
      function melody() {
     var audio = document.getElementById("html");
       audio.play();
       }
      </script>
```

Comment: I adjusted both the JS and the HTML but its still not responding or even being a button?

Comment: use the <audio> tag in html,i have edited the answer

Comment: If its still not working can you post more of your code please?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to play audio in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio id="audioContainer">
  <source src="myMp3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<p>Click the buttons to play or pause the audio.</p>

<button id="play" onclick="playMp3()" type="button">Play Mp3</button>
<button id="pause" onclick="pauseMp3()" type="button">Pause Mp3</button> 

<script>
const audioContainer = document.getElementById("audioContainer"); 

function playMp3() { 
  audioContainer.play(); 
} 

function pauseMp3() { 
  audioContainer.pause(); 
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

To add images to the background of the buttons

```
var play = document.getElementById("play");
var pause = document.getElementById("play");
play.innerHTML = '<img src="images/play.png" />';
pause.innerHTML = '<img src="images/pause.png" />';
```

Comment: Allright thanks, they are now buttons and there is audio! I just cant get the image to work. He can't find my image it seems..                                                           src="/Bureaublad/HKU/Jaar2/Manifest/Lyanna/messages-05.png" />';
I have now lead the way to the location but the img can't be found. Am i doing anything wrong in this part? Thanks !

Comment: Hey, you need to use a path relative to your file. If your root directory is 'myProject', your image folder is in that folder inside a subfolder called images, and your script is inside the root (project folder) you would use './images/myFile.png'

Comment: Its all in the same folder! No images folder. I can't get the img to work as a button. They keep being separate. I tried to make it a background img, but that doesn't work either! Really weird cause I thought this would work!

Comment: You can also use a div instead of a button. If you use <div id="something></div> var something = document.getElementById('something');

something.style.cursor = 'pointer';
something.onclick = function() {
   playMp3()
};

Comment: Then the img disappears.. I dont know anymore haha

Answer (score 0):

You need an  element in your html with the src set to your sound file, also give it an id. Grab a reference to that audio element with document.getElementByID and set it to a variable. Set an onclick attribute on your button and inside that function defintion chain the play() method off of your variable that references your audio element.

```
<audio src="./myaudio.mp3" id="myAudio"></audio>
<button onclick="playAudio()">Click To Play Audio</button>

<script>
    let myAudio = document.getElementByID("myAudio");
    function playAudio(){
        myAudio.play();
    }
</script>
```